# Problems with setting TableColumn width in FXML using CSS

Tags: css, javafx, fxml

Here is my `.fxml` code:

```
<TableColumn id="tableColumnVertical" text="">
    <graphic>
        <VBox>
            <Label text="text"/>
        </VBox>
    </graphic>
</TableColumn>
```

Here I have simplified `.css` code:

```
#tableColumnVertical {
    -fx-background-color: Lime;
    -fx-min-width: 40;
    -fx-max-width: 40;
}
```

This doesn't set width of `TableColumn` but sets background. Why?

I can use this code:

```
<TableColumn id="tableColumnVertical" text="" minWidth="40" maxWidth="40">
```

and it works. Why inline works and `.css` does not?

While writing this post I tried adding `-fx-pref-width: 40;` to `.css` and now it also works.

1) I would like know why inline works and `.css` does not (while `background-color` works)? Why after adding `prefWidth` it started to work?

2) Can I use both `fx:id` and `id`?

3) Also, in some SO answers I saw people advice to use `styleClass` to set style. When should I use `styleClass`?

Edit:

> a TableColumn also contains the necessary properties to:
>
> - Be resized (using minWidth/prefWidth/maxWidth and width properties)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html

Not sure if this is accurate, but I decided to post this edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The `-fx-pref-width` is setting the property of the `TableColumnHeader` (same for `-fx-min-width`, see below). Setting this property via CSS is buggy: [JDK-8087822](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8087822).
2. You can use both `fx:id` and `id`. If you only set `fx:id` it will also be used for the `id`. If you set both, the `id` is used for CSS and the `fx:id` is used for injecting the instance into a controller.
3. You would add a style class if you want to style many nodes the same way.

---

*Note: The following mostly deals with implementation details for JavaFX 11.0.1 (at least, I couldn't find documentation).*

The problem is the difference between `TableColumnBase.minWidth` and `Region.minWidth`. The former is not styleable from CSS because it is not a `StyleableProperty`. The latter is and it is that property that defines the `-fx-min-width` CSS property.

When you do:

```xml
<TableColumn id="tableColumnVertical" text="" minWidth="40" maxWidth="40">
```

You are setting the `minWidth` property of the `TableColumn` using a [property setter](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#property_setter_elements). It is not analogous to setting the CSS property.

However, the *JavaFX CSS Reference Guide* does [document](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#tableview) that `TableColumn` is part of the substructure of a `TableView`. This would seem to indicate you can style the column via CSS. But again, non of the properties are actually styleable; the `getCssMetaData()` method returns `Collections.emptyList()`.

`TableColumnBase` does implement `Styleable` (where `getCssMetaData()` comes from) which means it has the following method: `getStyleableNode()`. The `TableColumn` implementation of this method, once the `TableView` has been displayed, returns an instance of [`TableColumnHeader`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/skin/TableColumnHeader.html). What this means is any CSS applied to the `TableColumn` is *actually* applied to the `TableColumnHeader`. It is this latter class that extends `Region` and thus has the styleable `minWidth` property. And from some testing the `minWidth` property of the `TableColumnHeader` instance is set as expected.

The problem appears to be that the `minWidth` of the `TableColumnHeader` has no affect on the `TableColumn`. The implementation only takes `TableColumn.minWidth` into account. And this unfortunately means you won't be able to set the `minWidth` of the `TableColumn` from CSS.

This behavior *might* be a bug.

Comment: I will test some more things, for now `-fx-pref-width` works.